# How can I define Global variable with binding in Extjs 6?

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm

I'm developing a web application using [Extjs-6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/index.html). I have some variables. I'm using these variables in application several times.

`Variable_1`: One time in `panel_1`, One time in `Form_1`, and etc.
`Variable_2`: One time in `panel_1`, One time in `Form_2`, and etc.

These variables may frequently change and so we can change these variables in views(all `panels` and `forms`).

**How do I implement these features**? **Can I define as follow**?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',
    Variable_1: 'Variable1',
    Variable_2: 'Variable2',
    autoCreateViewport: true,

    controllers: [
        ...
    ]
});
```

**How can I use** `bind` **here**?

**Can I define a parent** `viewModel` **with statics variables and then all of**`parent` `viewModel` **property set to it** ?

Comment: Do you found a solution to your problem? I'm currently in the same situation.

Comment: Unfortunately no.